# How to make projectile propelled from object move towards specific point in Unity3d?

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine

I have a moving object which will propelled a projectile from it when you press shift key

I want my projectile move to specific point (0,0,10)

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
if (Input.GetKey("right shift")||Input.GetKey("left shift")) {
            Rigidbody clone;
            clone = Instantiate(projectile1, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            clone.velocity=new Vector3(0,0,10);
```

any one can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a constant velocity, use MoveTowards instead: MoveTowards(pointA, pointB, delta) returns a point in the line pointA-pointB distant delta units from pointA - and clamped to pointB, thus it never goes beyond the destination point.

```
if (Input.GetKey("right shift")||Input.GetKey("left shift")) {
            Rigidbody clone;
            clone = Instantiate(projectile1, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            clone.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(0,0,10), Time.deltaTime * speed); }
```

where speed is in meters (or units) per second.

Comment: what is the role of delta?

Comment: @Mohammed It means that if you are moving toward target, then maxDistanceDelta is the distance added to step from current toward target. If the actual distance remaining is less than maxDistanceDelta, it will be placed on target position.

So, if maxDistanceDelta is 5, every call will move current 5 units closer to target. It will never "overshoot" the target.

Tyically you will multiply the maxDistanceDelta parameter with delta time.